# WebView is taller than needed, lots of white space

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView inside of ScrollView (with more stuff around), the webview height is set to `wrap_content`.

That works great on Android 4.0+, the webview expands to display all the content and the scroll works great.

But I'm also testing on Android 2.3.3 (Galaxy S2) and the height is way taller than the content, so I'm getting a lot of empty space before the rest of the layout.

To solve it :

I try to wait for the page to load, then get the content height in Javascript and call a method in the Java code that will resize the webview to the proper height.

The problem is that the height I'm getting is also huge (more than 7000px when the content actually is about 400).

With `document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height`, I get 1

With `contentDiv.offsetHeight` (or scrollHeight, clientHeight) , I get 7000...

With jquery `.height()`, I also get 7000 !

So if you have another solution to WebView wrap the content... or know why the height is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution !

To make it simple : make the view in your xml layout `0dp`.
Then, when the page is loaded, make the view `wrap_content`.
This looks ok, but in reality the view is stuck in an infinite loop of onSizeChanged being called with either the good size or way more. So I have overridden the method and don't propagate the event once the view has the right size.

Here is the complete code of my custom webview, (in C#).

```
public class WebViewFixWrap : WebView
{
    private bool stopResize = false;

    public WebViewFixWrap (Context context) :
        base (context)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    public WebViewFixWrap (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
        base (context, attrs)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    public WebViewFixWrap (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
        base (context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    void Initialize ()
    {
        SetWebViewClient (new WebViewClientCustom ());
    }

    public override void SetWebViewClient (WebViewClient client)
    {
        base.SetWebViewClient (client);
        if(!(client is WebViewClientCustom))
            throw new Exception ("WebViewFixWrap requires a WebViewClientCustom, or make sure to implement the same logic in your client.");
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        if (!stopResize) {
            base.OnSizeChanged (w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }
        if (h < oldh) {
            stopResize = true;
        }               
    }

    class WebViewClientCustom : WebViewClient
    {
        public override void OnPageFinished (WebView view, string url)
        {
            var param = view.LayoutParameters;
            param.Height = LayoutParams.WrapContent;
            view.LayoutParameters = param;
            base.OnPageFinished (view, url);
        }
    }
}
```

This works from Android 2.3.3 to 4.4 so no special case to do in the code.